Migrating Kotlin Android Studio project from Empty Activity to Empty Views Activity
As I've been working for a while to my current Android project I've managed to do some progress but just realised my actual project doesn't have the layout folder with the main activity in it. After searching on Internet about this problem I found the answer that states that instead of an Empty Activity project I should use an Empty Views Activity project when doing the setup. A rookie mistake I admit, but my actual question is if there is any way of converting my actual project to the desired type (from Empty Activity to Empty Views Activity) without creating a new project and copying all the files? If not, I will do it, but I was wandering if there is any way of shortening the effort.

just add the layout folder in the resources folder manually

Yep. I thought about this. So I guess this is enough to solve the problem. Not any other things missing that should be done.

Instead, you could do your UI including the layout with Compose and you won't even need the layout folder. That's the recommended way and that's why it was missing in Empty Activity.
